# .htaccess deny all except some directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a folder that I wish to deny access to, but I wish there to be a subdirectory (and all its files and any subdirectories) that is accessible.

Sample directory structure:

```
/modules/
/modules/gallery/public/manifest.xml
/modules/gallery/public/js/core.js
/modules/gallery/public/css/master.css
/modules/news/public/images/status.png
/modules/news/public/css/style.css
```

The .htaccess file needs to be in "modules" as its subdirectories are user provided (they are plugins to a CMS), each user provided folder might have a "public" directory and only files and folders in "public" should be accessible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set an environment variable if the request contains a `/public/`, doing something like this in your htaccess file in the **modules** directory:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI /public/ ispublic=1
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=ispublic
```

If you want to be even more restrictive, you can tweak the `/public/` regex to include depth, for example, only 1 directory deep into **modules**:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/[^/]+/public/ ispublic=1
```